Partition form of the KL divergence.
A definition of $KL$ divergence is the following:
$$
KL(P||Q)=\underset{\mathcal{Z}}{\sup}KL(P_{\mathcal{Z}}||Q_{\mathcal{Z}}),
$$
where $Z$ is any finite partition of the underlying sample space and $P_{\mathcal{Z}},Q_{\mathcal{Z}}$ be the respective discrete distribution induced by the partition. From data processing, we know that finer partitions increase the $KL$ divergence, that is, if $\mathcal{Z}_1$ and $\mathcal{Z}_2$ are finite partitions such that $\mathcal{Z}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{Z}_2$ then we have:
$$
KL(P_{\mathcal{Z}_1}||Q_{\mathcal{Z}_1}) \leq KL(P_{\mathcal{Z}_2}||Q_{\mathcal{Z}_2}).
$$
Assume that the underlying sample space $\mathcal{X}$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, that $P,Q$ are two equivalent measures, i.e., they are absolutely continuous with each other and that the supports of both distributions is exactly $\mathcal{X}$. Also, assume that $\mathcal{X}$ has finite positive volume to rule out finite/or countable sample spaces.
My question is the following: Start with a finite partition of $\mathcal{X}$ say $\mathcal{Z}_{0}$ and progressively refine it such that $\mathcal{Z}_{i} \subsetneq \mathcal{Z}_{i+1}$ for all $i={0} \cup \mathbb{N}$. Then is the sequence
$$
KL(P_{\mathcal{Z}_i}||Q_{\mathcal{Z}_i})
$$
a strictly increasing sequence and is it true that $\lim_{i \to \infty} KL(P_{\mathcal{Z}_i}||Q_{\mathcal{Z}_i})=KL(P||Q)$?
Edit: We make an additional assumption that  $\lim_{i \to \infty}\underset{Z_{i,k}\in \mathcal{Z}_i}{\sup} \mathrm{diam}(Z_{i,k})=0$ and for every $Z_{ik} \in \mathcal{Z}_i$ we have that $\lambda(Z_{ik})>0$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

You can refine partitions in one region of the space, while keeping another region super crude, and that immediately means you wouldn't converge to the true KL with such a sequence. You would at least need some property like the norm of the partitions decaying to $0$.

I just noticed that the setup still allows $P, Q$ to have atoms (just mix a uniform law with a spike measure). If we then place atoms in a way such that a sequence of atoms converges to but doesn't contain another atom, then things might get weird around that accumulation point. I'd suggest trying to make sure that doesn't ruin things.

The obstruction which allows super crude partition in one area and super refined partition in another- feels like the only obstruction to the convergence.  I will impose an assumption on the partition sequence to rule this out. I did leave room for the distributions to have atoms. Intuitively it feels that shouldn't be an obstruction.

In the case of atoms converging to atoms, if the partitions are refining everywhere, that is say $\lim_{i \to \infty}\underset{Z_{i,k}\in \mathcal{Z}i}{sup} \lambda(Z{i,k})=0$ ,where $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure, why would it become weird? It seems the as the partitions become more refined they capture precisely more of the atom sequence tail.

One would hope so, but for each finite step, some chunk of the tail remains merged, and this reminds me strongly of certain scenarios with a sequence of $L_1$-converging laws on
the naturals for which KL does not converge  (e.g., this ), and that can possibly break things. This seems to be the only obstruction, so I was trying to suggest that making sure it doesn't happen would give good intuition (or possibly give a counterexample).

Thanks for reminding me about lsc of KL divergence. How about this argument: Construct measure $P_i(A)=\sum_{Z_{ik}\in \mathcal{Z}i} \frac{\lambda(A \cap Z{ik})}{\lambda(Z_{ik})}P(Z_{ik})$ and similarly $Q_i$. Then I think we can argue (by Portmanteau lemma for bdd cts function on $\mathcal{X}$) that $P_i$ converges weakly to $P$ and $Q_{i}$ converges weakly to $Q$. Then lsc implies $\underset{i \to \infty}{liminf}D(P_i||Q_i) \geq D(P||Q)$, but $D(P_i||Q_i)=D(P_{\mathcal{z}i}||Q{\mathcal{z}_i}) \leq D(P||Q)$. Hence we have shown the convergence.

I think the norm partition assumption might be crucial show the weak convergence. And if this argument goes through then it indeed was the only obstruction.

Ah, of course, it's lsc! I somehow had the sign wrong in my head. I think that's good to go then, yeah - norm dying gives weak convergence easily (using the bounded-Lipschitz test function part of Portmanteau is clearest to me), and bosh. It'd be nice if you could write an answer (and accept it), so that things are clearer for future readers.

Actually it might require an assumption on the diameter of the partitions rather just on the lebesgue measure norm dying out uniformly. The issue is the partitions maybe becoming smaller and smaller in one direction while still maintaining their length in another direction. This can cause issue in the weak convergence.

Yup - by norm I meant precisely the largest of the diameters of the parts ( this at least is the term I remember from Riemann integration theory), hence the bounded-Lipschitz bit being easy. In any case, thanks for writing the answer!

Under the assumptions given, let us create for each $i$ the following measure:
$$
P_i(A)=\sum_{Z_{ik} \in \mathcal{Z}_i} \frac{\lambda(A \cap Z_{ik})}{\lambda(Z_{ik})}P(Z_{ik})
$$
and similarly $Q_i$. Now for any bounded real valued Lipschitz continuous function $f$ with Lipschitz parameter $L$ on $\mathcal{X}$ we have
$$
\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(x) \, \mathrm dp_i(x)=\sum_{Z_{ik} \in \mathcal{Z_i}}\frac{\int_{Z_{ik} \cap \mathcal{X}}f(x) \mathrm d\lambda(x)}{\lambda(Z_{ik})}P(Z_{ik}).
$$
Now, by Lipschitzness of $f$ and assuming $i$ large enough that $\underset{k}{\sup} \quad \mathrm{diam}(Z_{ik}) \leq \delta$ we have that:
$$
\sum_{k}f_{m}(Z_{ik})P(Z_{ik}) \leq \int_{\mathcal{X}}f(x) \, \mathrm dp_i(x) \leq \sum_{k}f_{m}(Z_{ik})P(Z_{ik})+L \delta
$$
where $f_m(Z_{ik})=\underset{x \in cl(Z_{ik})}{\inf}f(x)$. Now the term $\sum_{k}f_{m}(Z_{ik})P(Z_{ik})$ converges as $i \to \infty$ to the Lebesgue integral  $\int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x) \, \mathrm dP(x)$(by definition of Lebesgue integral and assumption on the partitions). Thus, we have shown that:
$$
\int_{\mathcal{X}}f \, \mathrm dP_i(x) \rightarrow \int_{\mathcal{X}}f \, \mathrm dP(x)
$$
for all bounded Lipschitz continuous functions. Then, by Portmanteau lemma, $P_i$ converges weakly to $P$ and, similarly, $Q_i$ converges to $Q$. Then, by lower semi-continuity of $KL$ divergence we have that:
\begin{equation}\label{eq1} 
\underset{i \to \infty}{\liminf}KL(P_i||Q_i) \geq KL(P||Q).
\end{equation}
But we also observe that
$$
KL(P_i||Q_i)=KL(P_{\mathcal{Z}_i}||Q_{\mathcal{Z}_i}) \leq KL(P||Q).
$$
Hence, we also have that:
$$
\underset{i \to \infty}{\limsup}KL(P_i||Q_i) \leq KL(P||Q).
$$
The previous inequality with this gives the convergence result required.
